# Retrofit HTTPS connection not working in Android

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, retrofit, okhttp

I am getting a trust anchor error. I tried http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/25364/Get-OkHttpClient-which-ignores-all-SSL-e for the https connection but this returns below error.

```
 D/Retrofit﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
```

Comment: have you tried researching this error on your own?  That link didn't even have any context.  It was just a code snippet with no explanation.  Do you need a certificate installed for it to all work?

Comment: Yes @matt, could you direct me or provide me the certificate file (which works for all)

Comment: Seems like website you are trying is using **self signed certificate**, Try extracting certificate from website and include it in your code.

Comment: i got the crt file from service team but still it throws javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following sample code:

```
    private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
        final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        return new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        try {
                            originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        try {
                            originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
            throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_cert); // your certificate file
        Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        caInput.close();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

Then you can set the OkHttpClient in your project like the following:

```
okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
```

Regarding `setHostnameVerifier`, look like that you have a solution in the link in your question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is the certificate, because from volley and iOS the https works fine without any certificate attached. (getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_cert))

Comment: You mean your issue has been solved without using cert file?

Comment: Yes, when i tried form my iOS this been working with basic setup without crt file.

Comment: did you find its solution? I am stuck in same problem